# No margin / padding bottom on css grid?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, margin

margin bottom seems to disappear on css grid when overflow appears.

no matter which way i approach the layout of my page (flexbox, css grid, fixed) i seem to loose margin/padding bottom when using css grid.

an example of the issue:

HTML

```
<div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nav">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="article">
       <div class="settings__grid">
        <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #FAF9F8;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.article {
  background: #F3F3F5;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
}

.settings__grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(32rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 14rem;
  grid-gap: 3rem;
}

.settings__grid-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
  }
  .article {
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzWmeg

i expect the margin/padding to be consistent to what i define on parent but it doesn't and disappears / collapses

Answer (score 4):

The problem is merely in setting a `height` on `.article`; this sets the height to be the **initial** viewport (with no consideration given to the scroll).

Removing this `height` solves the problem:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #FAF9F8;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.article {
  background: #F3F3F5;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  /*height: calc(100% - 20px);*/
  padding: 10px;
}

.settings__grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(32rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 14rem;
  grid-gap: 3rem;
}

.settings__grid-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
  }
  .article {
    /*height: calc(100% - 80px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nav">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="settings__grid">
    <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="settings__grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, it works. keeping this in mind going through my project and i seem to still be having the same issue, although the parent is not set to height: 100% but rather flex: 1. i take it this is causing the issue again. i also need to keep the grid at 100% height so the children can be 1fr on desktop devices. is there any chance you could take a look? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwMLoz

Comment: I was forgetting about the height I set in my grid-layout container. Removing the height worked like a charm for setting margin-top for some columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the after to do my trick:

```css
&::after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  height: 16rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```